# Al correr mi JFrame me sale vacío

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, jframe

Tengo un programa que consiste en un `JFrame` que contiene imágenes repartidas en el frame.

Tengo un problema, lo que pasa es que cuando ejecuto el programa no me sale nada, sólo me aparece el Frame vacío,
¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

El código del JFrame es este:

```
package Frames;

/**
 *
 * @author Daniel
 */
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {
boolean estado;
int contar;
String nombre;
    /**
     * Creates new form Ventana
     */

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pecera = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        monopoly = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        florero = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mono = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        manzana = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        llaves = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        libro = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lampara = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        hueso = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        encendedor = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        terraquio = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        globo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        espejo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        escalera = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        alfombra = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        fosforo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        gato = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cuadro = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        avion = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        estambre = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cuchara = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        percheo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        perro = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        plato = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        periodico = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        puerta = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tijera = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mesa = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        equipo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tabrete = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        estrella = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        pajaro = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        reloj = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jButton5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jButton5.setText("jButton5");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton5);
        jButton5.setBounds(725, 613, 150, 40);

        jButton4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jButton4.setText("jButton4");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton4);
        jButton4.setBounds(555, 613, 150, 40);

        jButton3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jButton3.setText("jButton3");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton3);
        jButton3.setBounds(375, 613, 160, 40);

        jButton2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton2);
        jButton2.setBounds(195, 613, 160, 40);

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(10, 613, 160, 40);

        pecera.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/pecera.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(pecera);
        pecera.setBounds(60, 310, 70, 70);

        monopoly.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/monopoli.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(monopoly);
        monopoly.setBounds(530, 220, 100, 90);

        florero.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/florero.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(florero);
        florero.setBounds(390, 320, 40, 80);

        mono.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/mono.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(mono);
        mono.setBounds(750, 220, 50, 60);

        manzana.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/manzana.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(manzana);
        manzana.setBounds(440, 360, 30, 40);

        llaves.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/llaves.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(llaves);
        llaves.setBounds(290, 540, 34, 40);

        libro.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/libros.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(libro);
        libro.setBounds(50, 390, 80, 80);

        lampara.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/lampara.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(lampara);
        lampara.setBounds(200, 390, 90, 100);

        hueso.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/hueso.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(hueso);
        hueso.setBounds(80, 530, 100, 40);

        encendedor.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/encendedor.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(encendedor);
        encendedor.setBounds(820, 370, 50, 50);

        terraquio.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/tierra.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(terraquio);
        terraquio.setBounds(780, 490, 90, 120);

        globo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/globo.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(globo);
        globo.setBounds(140, 0, 120, 162);

        espejo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/espejo.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(espejo);
        espejo.setBounds(200, 240, 50, 80);

        escalera.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/escalas.png"))); // NOI18N
        escalera.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);
        getContentPane().add(escalera);
        escalera.setBounds(730, 310, 90, 140);

        alfombra.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/tapete.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(alfombra);
        alfombra.setBounds(720, 420, 120, 60);

        fosforo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/cigarros.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(fosforo);
        fosforo.setBounds(390, 390, 50, 38);

        gato.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/gatico.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(gato);
        gato.setBounds(640, 470, 110, 90);

        cuadro.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/cuadro.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(cuadro);
        cuadro.setBounds(720, 0, 160, 190);

        avion.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/avion.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(avion);
        avion.setBounds(30, 110, 90, 70);

        estambre.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/bola.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(estambre);
        estambre.setBounds(630, 540, 90, 60);

        cuchara.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/cuchara.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(cuchara);
        cuchara.setBounds(450, 360, 50, 40);

        percheo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/perchero.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(percheo);
        percheo.setBounds(670, 310, 30, 130);

        perro.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/perro.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(perro);
        perro.setBounds(10, 510, 70, 60);

        plato.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/plato.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(plato);
        plato.setBounds(430, 380, 50, 30);

        periodico.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/periodico.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(periodico);
        periodico.setBounds(60, 360, 60, 50);

        puerta.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/puerta.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(puerta);
        puerta.setBounds(740, 210, 80, 130);

        tijera.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/tijeras.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(tijera);
        tijera.setBounds(500, 540, 40, 40);

        mesa.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/mesita.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(mesa);
        mesa.setBounds(330, 360, 220, 160);

        equipo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/equipo.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(equipo);
        equipo.setBounds(570, 340, 80, 70);

        tabrete.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/mesanoche.png"))); // NOI18N
        tabrete.setText("jLabel18");
        getContentPane().add(tabrete);
        tabrete.setBounds(570, 390, 80, 110);

        estrella.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/estrellas.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(estrella);
        estrella.setBounds(260, -10, 130, 160);

        pajaro.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/paisaje.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(pajaro);
        pajaro.setBounds(310, 70, 170, 230);

        reloj.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Ventana/reloj.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(reloj);
        reloj.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 70);

        setBounds(0, 0, 896, 697);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
       estado=false;
       Inicio();
    }                                 

    private void Inicio(){
    reloj.setVisible(estado);
    globo.setVisible(estado);
    pajaro.setVisible(estado);
    avion.setVisible(estado);
    estrella.setVisible(estado);
    cuadro.setVisible(estado);
    espejo.setVisible(estado);
    mono.setVisible(estado);
    puerta.setVisible(estado);
    encendedor.setVisible(estado);
    escalera.setVisible(estado);
    percheo.setVisible(estado);
    alfombra.setVisible(estado);
    terraquio.setVisible(estado);
    estambre.setVisible(estado);
    gato.setVisible(estado);
    perro.setVisible(estado);
    hueso.setVisible(estado);
    llaves.setVisible(estado);
    tijera.setVisible(estado);
    libro.setVisible(estado);
    periodico.setVisible(estado);
    pecera.setVisible(estado);
    cuchara.setVisible(estado);
    manzana.setVisible(estado);
    mesa.setVisible(estado);
    tabrete.setVisible(estado);
    plato.setVisible(estado);
    florero.setVisible(estado);
    lampara.setVisible(estado);
    fosforo.setVisible(estado);
    monopoly.setVisible(estado);
    equipo.setVisible(estado);
    jButton1.setVisible(estado);
    jButton2.setVisible(estado);
    jButton3.setVisible(estado);
    jButton4.setVisible(estado);
    jButton5.setVisible(estado);
    }
    //eqipo,hueso, tijeras, tapete monopoly
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Ventana().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel alfombra;
    private javax.swing.JLabel avion;
    private javax.swing.JLabel cuadro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel cuchara;
    private javax.swing.JLabel encendedor;
    private javax.swing.JLabel equipo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel escalera;
    private javax.swing.JLabel espejo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel estambre;
    private javax.swing.JLabel estrella;
    private javax.swing.JLabel florero;
    private javax.swing.JLabel fosforo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel gato;
    private javax.swing.JLabel globo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel hueso;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lampara;
    private javax.swing.JLabel libro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel llaves;
    private javax.swing.JLabel manzana;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mesa;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mono;
    private javax.swing.JLabel monopoly;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pajaro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pecera;
    private javax.swing.JLabel percheo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel periodico;
    private javax.swing.JLabel perro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel plato;
    private javax.swing.JLabel puerta;
    private javax.swing.JLabel reloj;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tabrete;
    private javax.swing.JLabel terraquio;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tijera;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Igual te puede ayudar Daniel, que sale como autor del codigo xDD Pero ahora en serio. Es mucho codigo para ponerse a interpretar. Te recomiendo que añadas un log a cada paso que vas dando para ver donde falla. O entra en modo debug y poquito a poquito. Cuanndo tengas una idea de donde puede estar el fallo focalizado, pregunta aqui. un saludo

Comment: a no sino que estoy usando otro computador y el dueño me lo presto entonces por eso sn juego de encontrar objetose quedo eso ahi si lo estoy realizando yo es un juego de encontrar objetos

Comment: Intenta cambiar  estado=false; por true

Comment: Podrias instalarte la libreria WindowBuilder, que te permite crear los entornos graficos con mayor facilidad.

Comment: @paola Luis tiene razón, la próxima vez trata de poner un [mcve], por ejemplo si sabías que no teníamos las imágenes y que iba a dar null pointer exception por cada una podrías haber dejado únicamente un botónsin ponerle la línea que le pone la imágen.

Answer (score 1):

Hubo algo que hiciste con el código que te genera el netbeans:

- borraste el constructor

Ese constructor originalmente era

```
public Ventana() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Y se encargaba de que una vez creado el frame llamara al metodo que había generado para configurarlo, es decir, agregarle los botones y darle tamaño, si no llamas a ese método no tiene nada y sus dimensiones son de 0 por 0.

En la última línea de tu método `initComponents()` está la línea que le pone tamaño

```
setBounds(0, 0, 896, 697);
```

Cuando hagas un cambio y no sepas que hacer en el netbeans, asegúrate de primero abriendo el archivo de código que quieras revisar ir a la parte superior y seleccionar History.

[image: Botón de historial de netbeans]

Otra cosa que te podría ser de ayuda es hacer ejecutar el programa paso por paso.